# Grey background in vncviewer remote desktop

Tags: debian, vnc

I keep getting a grey background in my VNC viewer on my VPS, like so:

[image]

My `.vnc/xstartup` is as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh

unset SESSION_MANAGER
exec /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc

gnome-session --session=gnome-classic &
[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources

xsetroot -solid grey
xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
vncconfig -iconic &

x-terminal-emulator -geometry 1280x1024+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &
x-window-manager &
```

My server has the tightvncserver and everything else properly installed and configured to port 1.  What is going wrong? I'm on Debian 6.0.4

Comment: What are you expecting to see, a console?

Comment: No, a desktop.  I get a background.

Comment: A new session or the current session of X? You might want to read this question on [SU], http://superuser.com/q/326638/235569

Comment: According to that, all users logged in get their own desktop.  I just want to see a desktop interface.

Comment: OK, then lets set things straight. You went from work to home and wants to continue the same work (without the need of starting all the applications again) in your house, that?

Comment: No.  I just want to be able to dick around on the server in case a proxy is blocking a site i'm on.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9890/discussion-between-braiam-and-someone)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed on [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/9890), for what you want to do, opening a session over VNC, you (normally) don't need further configuration of the VNC server. Just delete the configuration file `.vnc/xstartup` and you will be fine.

Comment: So you're telling me that if I remove the line with -solid, it will work?

Comment: Still not working.

Comment: Yes.  I deleted both.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should log the vnc startup process. If you autostart vncserver use something like:

```
vncserver 1>/var/log/vnc 2>/var/log/vnc
```

if you meet an error like `xauth: (argv):1:  bad display name` ...
make sure /etc/hostname and /etc/hosts are consistent with the hostname.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else has similar problems: make sure your .vnc/xstartup file is executable!